# How to correct this WinForms ListView issue?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have this custom ListView:

```
     public class CustomListView : ListView
     {
         [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("uxtheme.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
         private extern static int SetWindowTheme(IntPtr hWnd, string pszSubAppName, string pszSubIdList);

         protected override void CreateHandle()
         {
             base.CreateHandle();
             SetWindowTheme(this.Handle, "explorer", null);
         }
     }
```

Just to get the Windows 7 theme, it's all the code.

The problem is, the selection bar rectangle is shown chopped, the inferior line doesn't appear, even if the rows height is increased.

[image]

It's fine in all other views Large, Small, Tile, List, except for Details. It is just a minor thing but I'd like to know if anyone has it, and best, if has the solution.

Comment: Code works for me on Windows 10, but I don't get the "bubble" look.  I get a lighter colored flat style.

Comment: Try turning GridLines to false.

Comment: The .Net `ListView` items Bounds are slighltly larger than the `SysListView32`. The `explorer` theme won't fit exactly. Even if you enlarge the row height (in relation to the items Font height). As @LarsTech noted, if you don't use grid lines, the focus rectangle will be entirely visible.